# When should I use try catch instead of then catch?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

The question is simple, but I haven't found the answer anywhere.

**When should i use try catch?** in the code below I use try catch to handle the return of a request:

```
async findUsers() {
    this.loading = true;

    try {
        const [users, count] = await this.api.get('/users/list');

        this.users = users;
        this.totalPages = Math.ceil(parseInt(count) / 10);
    }
    catch (error) {
        this.Messages.requestFailed(error);
    }
    finally {
        this.loading = false;
    }
}
```

Would it be a **good practice to use then(...).catch(...)?**

Comment: Not sure what `then catch` is? What's your implementation of it?

Comment: @JeremyThille `promise.then(...).catch(...)`

Comment: Aaaaaaaah, that wasn't clear. Well, as far as I'm concerned, `.then().catch()` is the "old" way. The newer `async/await` syntactic sugar is so much better to write, read, deal with and also avoids a fair amount of headaches.

Comment: @JeremyThille "and also avoids a fair amount of headaches" - also adds new ones and requires a proper understanding how it translates to raw promises. See the remark regarding `return await`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183434/3731501

Comment: Sorry, correction : it avoids _me_ a fair amount of headaches.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The difference is in how you're handing Promises.

If you're using `await` to handle the Promise then you wrap it in a `try/catch`.  Think of `await` as a way to make asynchronous operations semantically similar to synchronous operations.

But if you're *not* using `await` and are instead handling the Promise by appending `.then()` to it then you'd append a `.catch()` to that chain to catch failures from within the asynchronous operation.

Because a `try/catch` isn't going to catch an exception that happens from within the asynchronous operation if that operation isn't awaited.

Comment: So I understand that I should just use then(...).catch(...) if it's in a synchronous scope, where I don't need to wait, is that it?

Comment: @MatheusSantos: You may be overthinking the whole thing.  It's simply a matter of how you're handling the Promise.  If it's awaited, you can use a normal try/catch.  If it's not awaited and handled by callback functions then you'd need to use `.catch()` as part of that callback chain.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

When you use promises(**asynchronous operations**) then you need to handle the exception in case of an error. So In this case you can use **.then().catch(err) {}**

When you have synchronous code, use **try/catch** for exception handling.

Comment: Uh, `try/catch` is also very much used with asynchronous code (`async/await`), for that matter you can see an example of that in OP's question.

Comment: Correct buts that's applicable only for ES6 and above!

Comment: ...which all current browsers support? :) - IE doesn't! - But Microsoft themselves are officially killing IE, so who cares